# Web Crawler Issue in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, oop

This application will act as search engine to extract faculty related information from different (at least 200) academic institutes including Universities, colleges and other Training institutes. This includes faculty name, highest qualification, expertise area, expertise type (Teaching, research, coaching etc.), experiences (in years) and affiliation(s) and store them in the database.

I have to fetch data from 200 websites, which means every website has their own tags and other stuffs, Regular expression for each website will not be same, how can i do that, is there anybody can help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, i am doing in this way.

Comment: $regexp = '!<span id="rptrFaculty_ctl[0-9]+_rptrDepartment_ctl[0-9]+_rptrFacultyDetails_ctl[0-9]+_lblDesignation" class="txtsmall">(.*?)<\/span>!';
        preg_match_all($regexp, $name_url, $name);
        $f_name = $name[1];
        return $f_name;

Comment: But as you know, each time regular expression will be change, how can i manipulate this thing?

Comment: That's web scraping, not web crawling. You will have to write custom code for each one if each site isn't the same. Also, have you got written permission from each of the 200 institutes? you need it, otherwise, it's against the law and comes under copyright.

Comment: Yeah, i have got 150 websites administrator permissions which is our our universities in Pakistan. So, i don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I had this assignment in one of my previous companies to create a web-crawler to parse some of our websites and retrieve data. I had to use a headless browser ( i used Behat and mink as it is php based so came way easier to me to apply complex logic). The thing is that the websites were the same or really similar according to html code etc etc so my crawler run once and parsed all the sites. In your situation if the HTML code of each site is so different then you need to create dedicated regex-es for each of them. And of course you need to be allowed to do that!!!

Comment: So,how can i do it, if i write custom code for each website, then it will be messy. I think and time consuming.

Comment: Sir, main problem is i have to write custom code, there is restriction, no library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to use a headless browser for web crawling. I recommend this tool https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver.

To be able to crawl many websites you will need to implement many different crawlers, one for each website, once each one has your own html structure.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, problem is i have to code custom, i can't use any kind of library.

Comment: Creating custom tooling for web crawling will not work for every websites because some websites need javascript interaction and it forces you to use a headless browser to simulate client browsing. I think the maximum you will reach making by your own is just to take info using custom regular expression data collect parsing manually the DOM. It will take too much of yout time for a least nothing. Think better.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much, it's really helpful, actually problem is, we are working with a company which have some restriction. so i have to follow them, is there any possible other than using library, you think it may have. May be it will helpful for me.

Comment: You can read the source code of Dom Crawler https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler, it uses only pure PHP to that.

Comment: Ok thank you so much sir, it's really helpful for me.